# Can I create a word cloud of crowdfunding donors using word cloud?

Tags: text-mining, orange

I have a table like this:

```
FirstName    SecondName     Amount
Lorenzo      Perone         100
Mario        Rossi          25
...          ...            ...
```

I'd like to create a "word cloud" using "Amount" as weight, is it possible using the "word cloud" tool?
Thanks.

Comment: Word clouds are past their prime, but this should do if you insist: http://www.wordclouds.com/

Comment: There are many Word Cloud Generator available online and finding the best one is difficult but we have done this for you. We have found the top 8 Free [Word Cloud Generator](https://99generator.com/word-cloud-generator/) of 2018 You can check them now and select the best which suits you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will give you a simple solution using [R](https://www.r-project.org/) which requires the [wordcloud](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wordcloud/index.html) package. Of course there are many other solutions which do not require any programming skills.

The solution is a slight varient of this [R-Bloggers tutorial](https://www.r-bloggers.com/word-clouds-using-text-mining/). Feel free to have a look there for further formatting.

```
library(wordcloud)

words = c('Paolo Gentiloni', 'Matteo Renzi', 
          'Enrico Letta', 'Mario Monti', 
          'Silvio Berlusconi', 'Romano Prodi')
freq = c(100, 25, 50, 70, 95, 20)

wordcloud(words = words, freq = freq, min.freq = 1,
          max.words=200, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.35, 
          colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
```

It produces the following output:
[image: Wordcloud of Italien prime ministers and random numbers]

Btw. @Lorenzo Perone: Where the ones listed Italien names? I was not sure about that.

Comment: I've names and weights in a csv, could you explain me how to load a csv in R?

Comment: Within [this](http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/data-frame/data-import) it is explained.

Comment: I've loaded a csv correctly but when I run the script 
> wordcloud(mydata['Nome'], mydata['Contributo'], max.words = 300)

I read
Error in `[.data.frame`(words, ord <= max.words) : 
  undefined columns selected